# How can I correctly implement Schema.org with multiple lists using JSON-LD?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I am implementing Schema.org structured data into my magazine-style website and have a couple of concerns regarding the use of multiple lists.

I have two sections on my home page: 'Most Recent' and 'Most Popular'. Both sections contain five mini-articles each. I have considered both of these sections as 'lists'. This is an example of one section - the other is identical apart from the articles, obviously:

[image]

This is my Schema JSON-LD. I have cut this sample short at `...` for the sake of keeping the sample easily readable and have removed domains/names, etc. So far, I have only added the five articles from 'Most Recent' to this `ItemList` and testing it using Google's Structured Data Testing Tool returns zero warnings and zero errors:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "ItemList",
        "numberOfItems": "5",
        "itemListOrder": "Descending",
        "itemListElement": [
            {
                "@type": "Article",
                "position": "1",
                "mainEntityOfPage": {
                    "@type": "WebPage",
                    "@id": "/motoring/audi-launches-2019-sq8-tdi/"
                },
                "articleSection": "Motoring",
                "headline": "Audi launches 2019 SQ8 TDI",
                "datePublished": "2019-09-01",
                "dateModified": "2019-09-01",
                "image": "/content/uploads/2019/08/2019-audi-sq8-tdi-001-800.jpg",
                "url": "/motoring/audi-launches-2019-sq8-tdi/",
                "author": "The Author",
                "publisher": {
                    "@type": "Organization",
                    "name": "Company Name",
                    "url": "https://company.name",
                    "logo": {
                        "@type": "ImageObject",
                        "url": "https://company.name/logo.png"
                    },
                    "founder": "Founder",
                    "foundingDate": "2019"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "Article",
                "position": "2",
                "mainEntityOfPage": {
                    "@type": "WebPage",
                    "@id": "/gadgets-tech/meet-keysmart-the-smart-key-oraganiser/"
                },
                "articleSection": "Gadgets & Tech",
                "headline": "Meet Keysmart: The smart key organiser",
                "datePublished": "2019-09-01",
                "dateModified": "2019-09-01",
                "image": "/content/uploads/2019/08/the-smartkey-orgainser-001-800.jpg",
                "url": "/gadgets-tech/meet-keysmart-the-smart-key-oraganiser/",
                "author": "The Author",
                "publisher": {
                    "@type": "Organization",
                    "name": "Company Name",
                    "url": "https://company.name",
                    "logo": {
                        "@type": "ImageObject",
                        "url": "https://company.name/logo.png"
                    },
                    "founder": "Founder",
                    "foundingDate": "2019"
                }
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
</script>
```

However, as mentioned above, this `ItemList` is only for the five 'Most Recent' articles. I would now like to add structured data for the other section, 'Most Popular', and not sure how best to approach it.

1. Do I add the most popular five articles to the same `ItemList`, do I
   create a new `ItemList` or do I create a new script/JSON? How is
   this best achieved? Please provide an example.
2. Do I really need to add publisher/organization for each article like
   I have or can this be shortened somehow? It seems unnecessarily bulky 
   doing it as I have. I have read that adding 'Organization' data to 
   every page is bad practice (see link below) - does this apply here?
3. Each of these mini-articles points to a full article using
   `mainEntityOfPage`. Am I right using type 'WebPage' or should I be
   using type 'Article'?
4. If two lists are required, is there a way of telling search engines 
   that one list contains most recent items and one contains most 
   popular or is that unnecessary?

https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-do-not-put-organization-schema-markup-on-every-page/289981/

Comment: I recommend that you review the structure of the web page. I dare to assume that if you are implementing on the same web page the two sections you have indicated, then the web page may have a very low download speed for mobile devices. It may probably be useful to split one web page into several. This will facilitate the creation of data.

Comment: @nikant25 thanks for the suggestion. I have tested the download speed of this page numerous times, as SEO is very important to my business - it's pretty fast and passes Google's PageSpeed Insight test, scoring 98/100. I use the new HTML5 `srcset` and `sizes` attributes, with polyfill for older browsers, to tell the browser to use smaller, lower-resolution images for mobile devices, and what you see in my example is not necessarily what you see on mobile devices due to the responsive, mobile-first design.

Comment: @nikant25 in fact, after a couple of minor tweaks today, my home page now scores 100/100 for all four tests: performance, accessibility, best practices and SEO for both desktop and mobile devices using Lighthouse. So I'm very confident that the design of my page is not an issue, as you kindly pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general use HTML5 semantic element (main, section and so on) + Correct site outliner (H2 for each list and so on).

### Two lists

About your schema.
The best idea is to think in "microdata" view.

Your list is **not** nested

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul><li></li></ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul><li></li></ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Nested lists example:** https://schema.org/OfferCatalog#offer-3

### Use multiple json-ld scripts

In this case, I think the best/simple idea is to use **two seperate lists "objects"** (And add name/url/and so on for each list) - Example **outline** (Missing properties for short code):

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "ItemList",
        "name": "Recent Articles",
        "numberOfItems": "1",
        "itemListOrder": "Descending",
        "itemListElement": [
            {
                "@type": "Article",
                "position": "1",
                "headline": "I am recent Article"
            }          
        ]

    }
</script>
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "ItemList",
        "name": "Popular Articles",
        "numberOfItems": "1",
        "itemListOrder": "Descending",
        "itemListElement": [
            {
                "@type": "Article",
                "position": "1",
                "headline": "I am Popular Article"
            }          
        ]    
    }
</script>
```

[image]

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/96903/can-i-have-multiple-json-ld-scripts-in-the-same-page

#### Publisher as itemref

Try this idea:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/itemref
- https://moz.com/blog/search-marketers-guide-to-itemref-itemid

Example (Refernce Organization object to Article):

```
<!-- Organization -->
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Organization",
    "@id": "#Organization-name",
    "name": "My Organization"
}
</script>
<!-- Recent Articles -->
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "ItemList",
        "name": "Recent Articles",
        "numberOfItems": "1",
        "itemListOrder": "Descending",
        "itemListElement": [
            {
                "@type": "Article",
                "position": "1",
                "headline": "I am recent Article",
                "publisher": {
                 "@id": "#Organization-name"
                 }
            }          
        ]
    }
</script>
<!-- Popular Articles -->
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "ItemList",
        "name": "Popular Articles",
        "numberOfItems": "1",
        "itemListOrder": "Descending",
        "itemListElement": [
            {
                "@type": "Article",
                "position": "1",
                "headline": "I am Popular Article",
                 "publisher": {
                     "@id": "#Organization-name"
                 }
            }          
        ]    
    }
</script>
```

**Testing-tool output:**
[image: testing-tool]

#### mainentityofpage

Read this:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/87940/new-required-mainentityofpage-for-article-structured-data

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. The bounty I set has another 5 days left on it, so I would like to hang on to see if any other contributions come in, although, I can't see them being much better than what you have provided.

Comment: Thank you, Ezra. I have accepted your answer and have awarded you with the bounty. Keep up the good work.